# pip install uwsgi failing with "cannot find -lz"

Tags: python, fedora, uwsgi

I want to install uwsgi but I am unable to do so. It is a Fedora 18 64-bit system. python is version 2.7 and `yum install zlib` says: `Package zlib-1.2.7-9.fc18.x86_64 already installed and latest version`

Here is the last chunk of output when installing uwsgi.

```
*** uWSGI linking ***

gcc -pthread -o /usr/bin/uwsgi -L/usr/lib64 core/utils.o core/protocol.o core/socket.o core/logging.o core/master.o core/master_utils.o core/emperor.o core/notify.o core/mule.o core/subscription.o core/stats.o core/sendfile.o core/async.o core/master_checks.o core/offload.o core/io.o core/static.o core/websockets.o core/spooler.o core/snmp.o core/exceptions.o core/config.o core/setup_utils.o core/clock.o core/init.o core/buffer.o core/reader.o core/writer.o core/alarm.o core/cron.o core/plugins.o core/lock.o core/cache.o core/daemons.o core/errors.o core/hash.o core/master_events.o core/chunked.o core/queue.o core/event.o core/signal.o core/strings.o core/progress.o core/timebomb.o core/ini.o core/fsmon.o core/rpc.o core/gateway.o core/loop.o core/cookie.o core/querystring.o core/rb_timers.o core/transformations.o core/uwsgi.o proto/base.o proto/uwsgi.o proto/http.o proto/fastcgi.o proto/scgi.o lib/linux_ns.o core/zlib.o core/yaml.o core/dot_h.o plugins/python/python_plugin.o plugins/python/pyutils.o plugins/python/pyloader.o plugins/python/wsgi_handlers.o plugins/python/wsgi_headers.o plugins/python/wsgi_subhandler.o plugins/python/web3_subhandler.o plugins/python/pump_subhandler.o plugins/python/gil.o plugins/python/uwsgi_pymodule.o plugins/python/profiler.o plugins/python/symimporter.o plugins/python/tracebacker.o plugins/gevent/gevent.o plugins/gevent/hooks.o plugins/ping/ping_plugin.o plugins/cache/cache.o plugins/nagios/nagios.o plu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../libz.so when searching for -lz

/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/libz.so when searching for -lz

/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libz.so when searching for -lz

/bin/ld: cannot find -lz

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

gins/rrdtool/rrdtool.o plugins/carbon/carbon.o plugins/rpc/rpc_plugin.o plugins/corerouter/cr_common.o plugins/corerouter/cr_map.o plugins/corerouter/corerouter.o plugins/fastrouter/fastrouter.o plugins/http/http.o plugins/http/keepalive.o plugins/http/https.o plugins/http/spdy3.o plugins/ugreen/ugreen.o plugins/signal/signal_plugin.o plugins/syslog/syslog_plugin.o plugins/rsyslog/rsyslog_plugin.o plugins/logsocket/logsocket_plugin.o plugins/router_uwsgi/router_uwsgi.o plugins/router_redirect/router_redirect.o plugins/router_basicauth/router_basicauth.o plugins/zergpool/zergpool.o plugins/redislog/redislog_plugin.o plugins/mongodblog/mongodblog_plugin.o plugins/router_rewrite/router_rewrite.o plugins/router_http/router_http.o plugins/logfile/logfile.o plugins/router_cache/router_cache.o plugins/rawrouter/rawrouter.o plugins/router_static/router_static.o plugins/sslrouter/sslrouter.o plugins/spooler/spooler_plugin.o plugins/cheaper_busyness/cheaper_busyness.o plugins/symcall/symcall_plugin.o plugins/transformation_tofile/tofile.o plugins/transformation_gzip/gzip.o plugins/transformation_chunked/chunked.o plugins/transformation_offload/offload.o plugins/router_memcached/router_memcached.o plugins/router_redis/router_redis.o plugins/router_hash/router_hash.o plugins/router_expires/expires.o -lpthread -lm -rdynamic -ldl -lz -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -lpython2.7 -lcrypt

*** error linking uWSGI ***

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-root/uwsgi/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-QEHDKx-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-root/uwsgi
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, make sure you installed `python-dev`.

Next up, install `zlib-devel`.

```
yum install -y python-dev zlib-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

First up, I wouldn't worry about:

```
/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/libz.so when searching for -lz
/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libz.so when searching for -lz
```

They're only showing up because `-L` *adds* a directory to the library search path so it's still examining the 32-bit areas as well (and ignoring them).

However, according to the [RPM search page for your package](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/20046910/dir/fedora_18/com/zlib-1.2.7-9.fc18.x86_64.rpm.html), only the following files are provided:

- /usr/lib64/libz.so.1
- /usr/lib64/libz.so.1.2.7
- /usr/share/doc/zlib-1.2.7
- /usr/share/doc/zlib-1.2.7/ChangeLog
- /usr/share/doc/zlib-1.2.7/FAQ
- /usr/share/doc/zlib-1.2.7/README

You may want to examine that directory to see if there is a `libz.so` soft-linked to the `libz.so.1` entry. If not, create one with a command like:

```
ln -s /usr/lib64/libz.so.1 /usr/lib64/libz.so
```

(you may need to be root). Looking at the `libz` stuff in `/lib` should show you what it should look like, like:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Apr 24  2012 libxyzzy.so -> libxyzzy.so.2.1.0
```

Comment: +1 thank you. installing `yum install zlib-devel` fixed the problem per the other answer. thank you again for your detailed answer to get to the bottom of the problem.